# How to send data from Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub using x.509 certificate

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, x509certificate, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send data from my Raspberry Pi to an Azure IoT Hub with the code in this GitHub repository (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-node/tree/master/iot-hub/Tutorials/RaspberryPiApp). However, I would like to use an x.509 certificate instead of the Azure IoT Hub Device Connection String. I believe I have to modify the index.js file, but I am unsure what to change, please help.

Comment: In that repo there are [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-node/tree/master/iot-hub/Samples/device) available for [certificate auth](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-node/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/device/authentication_x509.js), are those useful?

Comment: I have tried it but i am not sure how to use it, and i am not sure how to integrate it into the index.js file which send all the data to the iot hub

Comment: Does this sample help? - https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/main/device/samples/javascript/simple_sample_device_x509.js

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the code with x.509 authentication, you would need a cert.pem and key.pem files. I have followed the steps outlined in the article [Quickstart: Provision an X.509 certificate simulated device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-x509?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp) I have generated the following set of certificates using the scripts.

[image]

I continued with the steps in the article to provision the device on the Azure portal using the device certificate generated in the above step.

I copied over the certificates generated to the Raspberry Pi device into the same directory where I have placed the index.js file. I have modified the x509 section of the `initClient` function of index.js file as follows to utilize the certificates.

```
if (connectionString.x509) {
// Read X.509 certificate and private key.
// These files should be in the current folder and use the following naming convention:
// [device name]-cert.pem and [device name]-key.pem, example: myraspberrypi-cert.pem
var connectionOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/rajesh/NodeApp/rasbpi-device-cert.pem', 'utf-8').toString(),
  key: fs.readFileSync('/home/rajesh/NodeApp/rasbpi-device-key.pem', 'utf-8').toString(),
  passphrase: '1234'
};
client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionStringParam, MqttProtocol);
client.setOptions(connectionOptions);

console.log('[Device] Using X.509 client certificate authentication');
}
```

> Please note that I have used MQTT protocol in this example. I observed an error when I test the same with AMQP protocol. I am not sure if this has to do with the approach I have used to generate the certificates.

If you did set a passphrase while generating the certificates, you can pass an empty string to the parameter as following `''` in the above connectionOptions declaration.

You can run the file using the following command from your Raspberry Pi

`sudo node index.js 'HostName=<YourHubName>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=<deviceId>;x509=true'`

Please find the output I get when I run the file using the certificates.

[image]